# regex findall to retrieve a substring based on start and end character

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following string:

```
6[Sup. 1e+02]
```

I'm trying to retrieve a substring of just `1e+02`. The variable first refers to the above specified string. Below is what I have tried.

```
re.findall(' \d*]', first)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following regex:

```
\b\d+e\+\d+\b
```

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - Word boundary
- `\d+` - Digits, 1 or more
- `e` - Literal `e`
- `\+` - Literal `+`
- `\d+` - Digits, 1 or more
- `\b` - Word boundary

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK1kL6/2)

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b\d+e\+\d+\b')
test_str = u"6[Sup. 1e+02]"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Up4jh6)

Comment: @BillGates: It can be neater, but you only provided one example. I guess all these values are inside square brackets, and they are located right before the closing one. If not, try just `\b\d+e\+\d+\b`.

Comment: `r` - raw string, where we do not have to use double slashes when building regexes, `u` means a Unicode string. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
first = "6[Sup. 1e+02]"
result = re.findall(r"\s+(.*?)\]", first)
print result
```

---

Output:

```
['1e+02']
```

---

Demo
http://ideone.com/Kevtje

---

regex Explanation:

```
\s+(.*?)\]

Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```

Comment: And if the input string has more `[]`s with no number in them? `6[Sup. 1e+02] [lorem ipsum]`? http://ideone.com/mh233v

Comment: the OP said: "__I have the following string:__ `6[Sup. 1e+02]`"